# Identify cells with only whitespace

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to apply this function

```
df.column.str.split(expand = True)
```

but the problem is there are some "empty cells", and when I mean "empty" it means that it has, for example, 6 white-spaces. Moreover, this is an iteration, so sometimes I have cells with 2 white-spaces.

How can I identify this "empty cells"?

PD:

```
df[df.column != '(6 spaces inside)']
```

works only for a particular case when there are 6 spaces.

EDIT 1: the df.column is an object type with people names (one or more than one, even errors)

EDIT 2: The idea is to remove this cell (row) in order to successfully applied the "str.split" function. This is an interation so sometimes I have cells with 6 spaces and other with 2 spaces.

EDIT 3: I can't remove all whitespaces because then I won't be able to apply the string separation (because I have names like "Jean Carlo" that I want to separate)

FINAL SOLUTION: I could solve the problem with the post that was signaled only adding a '+' because I have whitespaces in other cells.

Solution:

```
df = df.replace(['^\s+$'], np.nan, regex = True)
```

Comment: Would be coold if there was a function that `strip`s whitespaces from strings so they shrinkt to empty strings... not sure if that would be a solution to your comparison

Comment: you can use `.strip()` to strip out all whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].map(lambda x: x.strip())
```

This  will remove all leading and trailing spaces in df['Col1']

Comment: This can have unintended consequences. The OP only suggests that they want to identify cells that are entirely made up of whitespace, not affect whitespace on other strings

Comment: @roganjosh this is also a good point.  Would probably be better off mapping a function that uses regex to normalize any multi-space value by returning an single space (or whatever you want your flag character to be) then subselecting on the flag character

Comment: @zyd the duplicate I have proposed takes care of this

Comment: @roganjosh - it does seem to, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I tried zyd's solution and I have "'float' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Comment: @roganjosh You are correct. That is my mistake. I suppose an alternative option would be to use replace: `df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace('      ','6 spaces')`